# dynamic stylesheet languages & browser support

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, less

I am playing around with the idea of using a dynamic stylesheet language to add functionality to the traditional CSS. This would come in very handy for a project I am working on. Thus far I have my eye on [LESS](http://lesscss.org).

I would like to have it client based, so probably JS would be my choice. However, I have some questions that I hope someone could give me a tip on:

1. [LESS](http://lesscss.org) states it works in Chrome, Safari and FF on client side. What about IE? No support at all? How would the CSS behave in IE then?
2. are there any other comparable tools besides of LESS? I have looked into SASS, however it seems to be Ruby based, which I am completely unfamiliar with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LESS supports IE. I use that functionality.